# scoreboard in pygame not putting players in order or even not showing them

Tags: python, pygame, leaderboard

I have spent about 2 weeks creating a game on pygame and I am nearly finished the only part that I am trying to add now is a score board for first place and last place (The reason I did this was because I was not too sure how to create the middle rankings or places).

I have created a way to check on how if one of the four players is first. Firstly it checks which part of the track the player is on (top, bottom, left or right). Then it checks if the players laps is more than or equal to the other player laps this is incremented once you go over the finish line. Then it checks how many segments you have gone through. This is checked by once you go through the top left bottom or right part of the screen the segment amount will be incremented. Then depending on where the player is on the screen will compare a x-position or a y-position (example, if the player is on the top of the screen it will check if the xpos (x position) is > all the other xpos' of the other players) The rest of them are shown in the code.

[image: diagram]

```
if player_one.speed_y <= -1 and player_one.ypos > 30 and player_one.ypos < 662 and player_one.xpos < 100 and player_one.xpos > 0: #SHOWS WHICH PART OF TEH TRACK THE CHARACTER IS ON
        direction_one = "left" #meaning you are on the left side of the track
        if segment_lock_one == False:
            segment_amount_one += 1
            segment_lock_one = True

    elif player_one.speed_y >= 1 and player_one.xpos < 1200 and player_one.xpos > 1161 and player_one.ypos > 30 and player_one.ypos < 662:
        direction_one = "right"
        if segment_lock_one == False:
            segment_amount_one += 1
            segment_lock_one = True

    elif player_one.speed_x >= 1 and player_one.ypos > 0  and player_one.ypos < 30 and player_one.xpos > 100 and player_one.xpos < 1161:
        direction_one = "top"
        if segment_lock_one == False:
            segment_amount_one += 1
            segment_lock_one = True

    elif player_one.speed_x <= -1 and player_one.ypos < 700 and player_one.ypos > 600 and player_one.xpos > 100 and player_one.xpos < 1161:
        direction_one = "bottom"
        if segment_lock_one == False:
            segment_amount_one += 1
            segment_lock_one = True

    elif player_one.xpos >= 0 and player_one.xpos <= 100 and player_one.ypos >= 0 and player_one.ypos <= 40:
        direction_one = "corner top left"
        segment_lock_one = False

    elif player_one.xpos >= 1170 and player_one.xpos <= 1200 and player_one.ypos >= 0 and player_one.ypos <= 40:
        direction_one = "corner top right"
        segment_lock_one = False

    elif player_one.xpos >= 1161 and player_one.xpos <= 1200 and player_one.ypos >= 660 and player_one.ypos <= 700:
        direction_one = "corner bottom right"
        segment_lock_one = False

    elif player_one.xpos <= 100 and player_one.xpos >= 0 and player_one.ypos <= 700 and player_one.ypos >= 660:
        direction_one = "corner bottom left"
        segment_lock_one = False


    #CHECKING FOR FIRST PLACE IN EACH OF THE PLAYERS    
    #CHECK IF PLAYER ONE IS FIRST
    if direction_one == "left":#CHECKS POSITION #CHECKS ALL OF THE IF STATEMENTS TO SEE IF IT IS FIRST OR NOT
        if player_one_laps >= player_two_laps and player_one_laps >= player_three_laps and player_one_laps >= player_four_laps:#CHECKS HOW MANY LAPS HAVE BEEN DONE AND COMPARES IT TO THE OTHERS
            if segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_two and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_four:#HOW MANY SEGMENTS HAVE BEEN COVERED
                if player_one.ypos < player_two.ypos and player_one.ypos < player_three.ypos and player_one.ypos < player_four.ypos:#IF IT IS LESS THAN ALL OF THE OTHERS ON THAT CERTAIN PART OF THE TRACK
                    print("1st on left (player one)")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(one_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, one_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))

    if direction_one == "top":
        if player_one_laps >= player_two_laps and player_one_laps >= player_three_laps and player_one_laps >= player_four_laps:
            if segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_two and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_four:
                if player_one.xpos > player_two.xpos and player_one.xpos > player_three.xpos and player_one.xpos > player_four.xpos:
                    print("1st on top (player one)")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(one_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, one_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))



    if direction_one == "right":
        if player_one_laps >= player_two_laps and player_one_laps >= player_three_laps and player_one_laps >= player_four_laps:
            if segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_two and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_four:
                if player_one.ypos > player_two.ypos and player_one.ypos > player_three.ypos and player_one.ypos > player_four.ypos:
                    print("1st on right (player one)")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(one_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, one_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))

    if direction_one == "bottom":
        if player_one_laps >= player_two_laps and player_one_laps >= player_three_laps and player_one_laps >= player_four_laps:
            if segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_two and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_one >= segment_amount_four:
                if player_one.xpos < player_two.xpos and player_one.xpos < player_three.xpos and player_one.xpos < player_four.xpos:
                    print("1st on bottom (player one)")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(one_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, one_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))

    elif direction_one == "corner top left" or direction_one == "corner top right" or direction_one == "corner bottom right" or direction_one == "corner bottom left":
        pass


################################################################################################
    #CHECK IF PLAYER TWO IS FIRST
    if player_two.xpos <= 100 and player_two.xpos >= 0 and player_two.ypos >= 30 and player_two.ypos <= 660:#BASICALLY THE DIRECTION AND CHECKS IF IT IS ON THE CORRECT PART OF THE TRACK #on that certain part of the track
        if player_two_laps >= player_three_laps and player_two_laps >= player_one_laps and player_two_laps >= player_four_laps: #how many laps have been covered
            if segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_one and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_four:#checks how many segments have been covered (should be 12 altogether at the end)
                if player_two.ypos < player_one.ypos and player_two.ypos < player_three.ypos and player_two.ypos < player_four.ypos:#checks if the player is furthest ahead
                    print("1st on left")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(two_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, two_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))

    if player_two.ypos >= 0 and player_two.ypos <= 30 and player_two.xpos >= 100 and player_two.xpos <= 1100:
        if player_two_laps >= player_three_laps and player_two_laps >= player_one_laps and player_two_laps >= player_four_laps:
            if segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_one and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_four:
                if player_two.xpos > player_one.xpos and player_two.xpos > player_three.xpos and player_two.xpos > player_four.xpos:
                    print("1st on top")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(two_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, two_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))


    if player_two.xpos >= 1151 and player_two.xpos <= 1200 and player_two.ypos >= 30 and player_two.ypos <= 660:
        if player_two_laps >= player_three_laps and player_two_laps >= player_one_laps and player_two_laps >= player_four_laps:
            if segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_one and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_four:
                if player_two.ypos > player_one.ypos and player_two.ypos > player_three.ypos and player_two.ypos > player_four.ypos:
                    print("1st on right")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(two_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, two_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))

    if player_two.ypos >= 600 and player_two.ypos <= 700 and player_two.xpos >= 100 and player_two.xpos <= 1100:
        if player_two_laps >= player_three_laps and player_two_laps >= player_one_laps and player_two_laps >= player_four_laps:
            if segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_one and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_three and segment_amount_two >= segment_amount_four:
                if player_two.xpos < player_one.xpos and player_two.xpos < player_three.xpos and player_two.xpos < player_four.xpos:            
                    print("1st on bottom")
                    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OCRB', 40)
                    texto = basicfont.render('1st: ' + (" ") +  str(two_type), True, (0, 125, 255), (0, 0, 0))
                    logo_first = Player(200, 400, two_character_pic, 60, 60)
                    logo_first.draw()
                    textrecto = texto.get_rect()
                    textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
                    textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
                    screen.blit(texto, (200, 600))


    if player_two.ypos < 20 and player_two.ypos > 0 and player_two.xpos < 80 and player_two.xpos > 0: #TOP LEFT CORNER
        pass

    if player_two.ypos > 0 and player_two.ypos < 20 and player_two.xpos > 1200 and player_two.xpos < 1250: #TOP RIGHT CORNER
        pass

    if player_two.xpos > 1200 and player_two.xpos < 1250 and player_two.ypos > 680 and player_two.ypos < 700: #BOTTOM RIGHT CORNER
        pass

    if player_two.xpos < 80 and player_two.xpos > 0 and player_two.ypos > 670 and player_two.ypos < 700: #BOTTOM LEFT CORNER
        pass
```

the results are that player one cannot be shown when first and any other player cannot be shown when last and on certain parts of the track no players show up.

Answer (score 2):

If the track is always a convex polygon, I'd use an angle between player and start with vertex at the center of your track.

You can then use laps * 360 + angle to compare the progress of players.
[As illustrated here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/581Sb.png)

Quick and ugly example code, the solution are methods get_angle and Player.get_angular_score:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ('x','y'))


def get_angle(point, other):
    dx = other.x - point.x
    dy = other.y - point.y
    return math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = x
        self.laps = 0

    def get_angular_score(self, other: Point, start_angle):
        player_angle = get_angle(self, other)
        angle_between_player_and_start = player_angle - start_angle
        angle_between_player_and_start %= 360 # handle negative angle
        return angle_between_player_and_start + 360 * self.laps

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    center = Point(320, 240)
    start = Point(50, 50)
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdana", 30)
    player = Player(*start)
    start_angle = get_angle(start, center)
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    player.laps += 1

        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.y -= 2
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.y += 2
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.x -= 2
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.x += 2

        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), (player.x, player.y), 4)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 255), start, center)

        coords = font.render("x: {}, y: {}".format(player.x, player.y), True, (255,255,255))
        angle = font.render("Player score: {}".format(player.get_angular_score(center, start_angle)), True, (0, 255, 0))

        screen.blit(coords, (5,5))
        screen.blit(angle, (5, 400))

        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(.02)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I thank you very much for that idea. But I am only 14 and in year 9 so can you try to show me how I would do it

Comment: I am very sorry but that is just a bit too complicated for me at the moment. But thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 1):

The checks you have put in place for which player is winning are very long, IF you did want to change the leader board to include middle positions, you would have a LOT of work updating this code.

What I would suggest is adding something to your player class like `player.score` that will increase as the player moves along the map.  The score could increase with, say `100*lapNumber` every time you cross the finish line, `10*sectionOfCourse` every time you cross a checkpoint  and `distanceAlongSection` every frame as it moves. This way you can just check all your players for what `score` they have and you will know the rankings of all players.

```
class player()
    def update(self):
        currentSection = checkSection(self.pos)
        if(currentSection = (pastSection + 1)%totalSectionsPerLap): # NEW CHECKPOINT
            self.score += 10
            self.pastSection = currentSection
            if(currentSection == section[0]): #NEW LAP
                self.lap +=1
                self.score += 100
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I see what you mean but what value would distanceAlongSection and sectionOfCourse be

Comment: Can you try to show me it in my code (do you need all of my code)

Comment: I've added a start to my method, from this you'll need to define `checkSection()` to see if you are in TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM or RIGHT.  With this, even without checking positions along each section of the track, you can get a general idea of who is winning or not.  You'll have to write something more specific to see who is winning if two players are in the same section of the track, and a few other things but this is a good start

Comment: I have thought of another way. Once the player is over the finish line it the player's score will get incremented by the players laps and then multiplied by 100 and the same goes for sectors apart from multiplied by 10 and when you move one space your score automatically gets increased. Does that sound like it will work to you

Comment: That will be very close! Instead of "when you move one space your score automatically gets increased" you should make a function that tests how far along you are in a checkpoint (IF you have the actual points of your checkpoints, this could be `DISTANCE_FROM_LAST_CHECKPOINT - DISTANCE_TO_NEXT_CHECKPOINT`).  This will make sure that moving back and forth does not give you free points.

Comment: I will try my way first and if that does not work then I will do yours